# MySQL Regexp vs regex after MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I need to find in a MySQL DB all rows that contain in a specified column a string matching a pattern.

I used Regexp but it's too slow. I know about full text indexing or third-party software, but that looks more complicated.

I was wondering if it would be faster to select the column from the DB and then perform a regex search using `preg_match` (or something similar) on the result.

From your experience, do you think it would be faster?

Comment: Uh no. It will be slower. You have probably no index on the row you try to do regexp, thus ending up being slow.

Comment: The row in DB has an unique index, if that's the problem

Comment: `REGEXP`/`RLIKE` requires a scan, it does not/cannot use an index for lookups, so the presence of an index will not generally improve performance, but of course won't hurt it.  @CharlotteDunois is otherwise correct, fetching everything and filtering it in code will always be slower.

Comment: A fulltext index is not complicated, but generally cannot be used with patterns. Can add some example patterns and some example data to see if a fulltext index could work (or if there might be another way)? Otherwise, I agree with the rest, extracting the column first would be a lot slower.

Comment: Please discuss what the "string pattern" is.  There may be a workaround.